# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pulsate') in material-ui Button component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

This is **version** of **material-ui** that I am using :

```
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
"@mui/material": "^5.5.1",
```

This is how I imported Button component :

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
```

This is how I am using Button :

```
<Button variant="contained"
   className={styles.contactBtn}
   autoFocus
   onClick={handleClose}
>
   Close
</Button>
```

I am getting an error like this :  **Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pulsate')[image]**

I found this thread(solution) from github [Link](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16810) , but it did not solved my issue .
How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried removing each prop in button and checked whether it is working or not.

> I found, autoFocus prop should have value `true` or `false`.

> It does not set `defaultValue` as `true` or `false`, ideally it should set a `defaultValue`.

```
<Button variant="contained"
   className={styles.contactBtn}
   onClick={handleClose}
   autoFocus={true}
>
   Close
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`autoFocus` should have value true or false. It should not be null.

Read the mui docs for the same.
Mui has very well documented the solution to this problem.